# Disable help in Geogebra Classic 6

Tags: geogebra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9HiP.jpg)

How to deactivate the help that appears at the bottom right of the screen when you select a tool ?

I searched but I couldn't find it in the settings...

I thank you in advance for your help !!